Vanilla NGINX 50% Slower on Processing than cPanel’s Version?
I have NGINX configured on two LXC containers — one vanilla Debian and one AlmaLinux — trying to meet or exceed the performance of my older server running a cPanel managed installation of NGINX as a reverse proxy. However, my vanilla installations, whether with NGINX as a direct web server or caching reverse proxy over Apache, clocks in 54% slower than my older cPanel/WHM server’s NGINX implementation. This is despite the actual new server being as good or better hardware wise in every way over the one it is replacing.
Using ab -n 10000 -c 100 -k -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" -H "User-Agent: BenchmarkTool" https://———————.com/  to benchmark my configuration, requesting the most basic of pages on an AlmaLinux or Debian container takes 75ms; on the older cPanel/AlmaLinux install it takes just 46ms. In both cases, all but 1-2ms of that is “processing” according to ab.
I have a more convoluted configuration attempt with every directive I could throw at it to try to optimize things, attempting to distill some of the inscrutable layers of settings on the cPanel server to try to find the “magic” one that provides the better performance, but the result comes out the same as this simpler configuration:
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024; #Also tried 2048
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    server {
        server_name  ---------------.com _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
    
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 http2 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/t-------------.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/-------------.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}

I’ve run Geekbench on both servers and the newer one’s containers perform faster than the old one, just as I’d expect. I’ve run various disk I/O tests and found the two servers essentially indistinguishable on that count, both running on a reasonably fast SSD of equal speed.
When ab is running a 10,000 connection test, the container never shows more than 5% CPU usage.
Is there anything obvious I’m missing that might help get the new server’s NGINX performance down to the ~ 40ms processing range on a simple page, given that I know such is a realistic goal based on the other server’s performance?
(To be clear, since I know cPanel is frowned upon on here, I am not asking about how to configure cPanel; the new server is not running a control panel.)
Update (7/12/2024): I tried installed NGINX on directly on the Proxmox host that has the containers to see if that would show the containers to be the source of the substantial overhead. I also installed NGINX on a VPS I have from a cloud provider. In both cases, I still hit the same approximate performance barrier (~ 70ms processing time for a tiny webpage), with the containers maybe adding 3ms or so at worst. None of the attempts comes close to the cPanel server's ~ 40ms processing time.
Second Update (7/12/2024): I tried using wrk -t12 -c400 -d30s https://-----.com and using wrk the new server significantly outperforms the old server. Using NGINX as a reverse proxy on both, below are the results. So, perhaps there's something with ab rather than my server?
root@juniper:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# wrk -t12 -c400 -d30s https://---newserver----.com/testing.html
Running 30s test @ https://---newserver----.com/testing.html
  12 threads and 400 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency     4.11ms    6.34ms 231.47ms   87.84%
    Req/Sec    11.04k     4.50k   26.31k    67.78%
  3930823 requests in 30.07s, 1.11GB read
Requests/sec: 130701.72
Transfer/sec:     37.64MB

root@juniper:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# wrk -t12 -c400 -d30s https://---oldserver---.com/testing.html
Running 30s test @ https://---oldserver---.com/testing.html
  12 threads and 400 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency    70.01ms   34.05ms 358.01ms   74.22%
    Req/Sec   477.03    174.44     1.03k    68.58%
  169995 requests in 30.09s, 33.88MB read
Requests/sec:   5649.18
Transfer/sec:      1.13MB


Just added further research to try to determine if containerization was at fault. I do not believe it is.
